# FreeRadius fails to install at ./config

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to install FreeRadius 3.0.15. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded FreeRadius 3.0.15 from the official downloads page.

My issue is that when I go into the file and try to run `sudo ./configure`, the process terminates on

```
configure: error: "inconsistent LDFLAGS between -lssl '' and -lcrypto '-L/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/2472245c805ac63cb1eebc4df9c07ec6ee975313e737a5183d41504f3d3f5f9b/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/2472245c805ac63cb1eebc4df9c07ec6ee975313e737a5183d41504f3d3f5f9b/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'"
See `config.log' for more details
```

What does it mean for the LDFLAGS to be inconsistent, and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by reinstalling lcrypto with `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`. However, I'm now getting a new error:

```
configure: WARNING: FAILURE: rlm_rediswho requires: hiredis.h libhiredis.
```

So now I'm going to try to figure that out.

EDIT: figured out second error. Fixed with `sudo apt-get install libhiredis-dev`

In short, this was all just dependency issues.

Comment: It's just a warning, configure shouldn't fail because it can't find hiredis... Weird.